# Как вы реализуете валидацию форм?

Tags: jquery, javascript

На самом деле в каждом новом проекте меня мучает неопределенность в выборе валидации форм. То в одном плагине нет проверки на email, то нет проверки на only numbers и таких примеров привести можно очень много. В ответах я не хочу получить ссылки на поисковики. Просто напишите как проверяете формы вы. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

плагин jquery.validate

Answer (score 0):

Один раз сделал так: регулярку вписал в атрибут поля.

И навешал обработчик на каждый импут с проверкой по этой регулярке.